# Is it safe to update to OS Catalina while running Logic Pro X version 10.4.6?

Tags: catalina, software-update, logic

I have heard some negative reports concerning Logic's behaviour when updating to Mac OS Catalina. I also had a friend who updated and couldn't even open the program because it was way to glitchy and wouldn't run. Most of these reports are from a while ago, though. Does anyone know if it would be safe for me to update now?

Answer (score 1):

All the negative reports I could find center around [Catalina's lack of support for 32-bit code](https://9to5mac.com/2019/10/06/psa-logic-pro-on-catalina/) and heightened security that may affect 3rd party FX, plugins, and other software and hardware some folks use to supplement Logic Pro X.

If you use 3rd party software or hardware, check with the developer or manufacturer to make sure it is compatible.

[ProToolsExpert](https://www.pro-tools-expert.com/production-expert-1/2019/9/18/macos-catalina-compatibility-the-ultimate-pro-audio-guide-check-it-out-today-to-see-if-the-software-and-plug-ins-you-use-support-apples-1015-yet) has a searchable *Ultimate Pro Audio Guide to macOS Catalina Compatibility* chart with 152 developers listed.